# Open Outlook window from CRM2011 WebPage

Tags: outlook, dynamics-crm-2011, customization

I have the following requirement:

The customer has the possibility to "reply all" in an email. But the customer wishes to open up the Outlook "reply all" form by clicking reply all on the CRM2011 Email Entity Web Page.

Is this possible? At this moment I have not found any useful stuff to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know dynamics but if you craft a hyperlink with a mailto uri as the href it would open Outlook if it is set as the default mail client.

You would have to craft the list of recipients as you build the link:

```
<a href="mailto:someone@example.com,someoneelse@example.com">Send email</a>
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailto